# Is it possible to assign a variable inside a while loop in Java

Tags: java

This might be bad practice but I am trying to take in input from a user with the following conditions:
lowerBound must be lesser than upperBound
neither can be zero

and if any of those conditions are not met, I want to have them input new values for the variables

```
int lowerBound;
    int upperBound;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean loop = true;
    while(loop = true)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a lower bound:");
        lowerBound = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter an upper bound:");
        upperBound = input.nextInt();
        if(lowerBound > upperBound || lowerBound <= 0 || upperBound <= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Error lowerBound must be less than or equal to upperBound");
            System.out.println("Neither may be equal to zero, Try again");
        }
        else
        {
            loop = false;
        }
    }
    
    input.close();
```

Comment: `while(loop=true)` is not only redundant, but also an infinite loop. `while(loop)` will suffice. Also, what's the problem? The logic seems fine to me.

Comment: Actually while(loop=true) is an infinite loop. You're assigning the value to be true.

Comment: Also `while (1)` with `break` on exit condition would be a better choice, imho.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni You mean `while (true)`, for an integer is not a boolean in Java.

Comment: @mcemperor yeah, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

What you have will work because every time the if condition fails the while loop is force to repeat. Each repeatition will get the user to land on the input with out missing input. So short answer yes you can change a variable in a while loop. That is how we effctivlly break the loop.

Comment: The loop runs fine I copy pasted the code to double check:

Comment: @Aniox the loop never breaks because of the typo/incorrect comparison in `while(loop = true)`

Comment: @AlexRudenko I believe I had already pointed that out ina comment on the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a infinite loop because you put a assigment inside of the while, making loop always true regardless of whether it is set to false.

for this case, can be simplified like this:

```
int lowerBound;
int upperBound;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a lower bound:");
    lowerBound = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter an upper bound:");
    upperBound = input.nextInt();
    if(lowerBound > upperBound || lowerBound <= 0 || upperBound <= 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Error lowerBound must be less than or equal to upperBound");
        System.out.println("Neither may be equal to zero, Try again");
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}

input.close();
```